# The Yoneda lemma and a natural bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, yoneda-lemma, representable-functor, hom-functor

Let $S\colon\mathbf {Set}^{\cal A^{op}}\to \mathbf{ Set}$ be a functor.
How does it follow from the Yoneda lemma that the following is a natural bijection:

$\underline{\hom(A,-)\to SY   \quad\quad\quad }$

$\hom(\hom(,-A),-)\to S$

Here $Y\colon {\cal A} \to \mathbf{Set}^{\cal A^{op}}$ is the Yoneda embedding
with $Y(A)=\hom(-,A)$.

I know that the Yoneda lemma states that there is a natural bijection
for natural transformations from a $\hom(A,-)$ functor to a functor $K$ with this set:the image of $K$ under $A$: $K(A).$

[Here is the statement of the above bijection in question](https://books.google.cz/books?id=iXh6rOd7of0C&pg=PA82&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: That doesn't make sense, $\hom(A,-)$ is a functor and $SY$ a set, so what is $\hom(A,-)\to SY$ ?

Comment: What is $Y{}{}$?

Comment: I gave a reference in the last line of my question. I have just rewritten that from that page 82 in [Adamek Rosicky] book.

Comment: You forgot to give the meaning of $Y$. I happen to have a copy of the book, where the notation is introduced on page 3, but for most people it is not an obvious guess and a reference to page 82 is usually not enough; also Google may restrict access, depending on the IP. So it is much better to explain all relevant notation in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Yoneda Lemma is used twice.
In the following I avoid the notation $\hom{}$, so that the different categories involved are easier to distinguish. As in the (edited) question,
$Y\colon {\cal A} \to \mathbf{Set}^{\cal A^{op}}$ will denote the Yoneda embedding
with $YA = {\cal A}(-,A)$.

By the Yoneda Lemma, applied to ${\cal A}$, a natural map

$\varphi\colon {\cal A}(A,-) \to SY$

corresponds to an element of $(SY)A$.
But because $(SY)A = S(YA)$, such an element corresponds to a natural map

$\hat\varphi\colon \mathbf{Set}^{\cal A^{op}}(YA,-) \to S$

by the Yoneda Lemma, applied to $\mathbf{Set}^{\cal A^{op}}$.